# Set from powerset which gives nonempty intersection

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Have such question:

Let us have $S=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and let there be powerset $P(S)$. Prove that there exists such subset $F\subseteq P(S)$ that $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$ for any $A\in F$ and $B\in F$ and $|F|=2^{n-1}$

I might be missing point here, but could one make argument that $S\in P(S)$, so if $S\subseteq F$ and $\emptyset \not\subseteq F$, we get ourself proper $F$, in which any two elements have nonempty intersection.

Comment: So, you've got one element in your $F$, now you just need to add $2^{n-1}-1$ more. Note, if $S\in F$ and $\{1\},\{2\}\in F$, the statement is not true for all $A,B$. The phrase "for any" does not mean "for some." It mean any pair in $F$ has a non-empty intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a large family of subsets of $S$ whose members overlap. Notice that $2^{n-1}$ is a very nice number: it is the number of subsets of any set with $n-1$ elements. So, fix some $s$ in $S$, have a look at the collection $F_0 = \mathcal{P}(S\setminus\{s\})$, and throw $s$ back in to each of those sets: $F = \{A \cup \{s\} : A \in F_0\}$. That's the $F$ you want! 
Equivalently, let $F = \{A \subseteq S : s \in S\}$. Anyway, it is clear that $A \cap B \ne \varnothing$ for any two sets $A$, $B$ in $F$, because $A \cap B \supseteq \{s\}$.